# What is the best way to ensure the correctness of data returned by a SNMP query?

Tags: perl, snmp

I am working on code which uses the `snmp->get_bulk_request()` method to make SNMP queries to get interface table details from a network device.

The problem I am facing is that **sometimes**, the data I receive from the query is missing some detail. This is a transient issue.

I believe that placing a set number of retries will reduce the probability of error. But, as I go through the documentation for `snmp->get_bulk_request()`, I find a parameter called 
`maxrepetitions`. It is not clear to me from the documentation what this parameter does.

I am trying to figure out what effect the `maxrepetitions` parameter has when used with the `get_bulk_request` call method. I have gone through the documentation in "[get_bulk_request() - send a SNMP get-bulk-request to the remote agent](http://search.cpan.org/~dtown/Net-SNMP-v6.0.1/lib/Net/SNMP.pm#get_bulk_request%28%29_-_send_a_SNMP_get-bulk-request_to_the_remote_agent)" and found this:

```
$result = $session->get_bulk_request(
                          [-callback        => sub {},]     # non-blocking
                          [-delay           => $seconds,]   # non-blocking 
                          [-contextengineid => $engine_id,] # v3 
                          [-contextname     => $name,]      # v3
                          [-nonrepeaters    => $non_reps,]
                          [-maxrepetitions  => $max_reps,]
                          -varbindlist      => \@oids,
                       );
```

The default value for `get-bulk-request -maxrepetitions` is 0. The `maxrepetitions` value specifies the number of successors to be returned for the remaining variables in the variable-bindings list.

Specifically, my questions are:

1. Is adding `maxrepetitions` equivalent to adding retries for the query?.
2. Is retrying the right way to ensure the data is most probably correct?

If not, what is the best method to ensure the probability error is low in data returned by SNMP query?

Comment: 1) Have you tried using `snmpwalk` from the command line to duplicate the issue? (this might be difficult since you say the issue is transient, but could rule out issues in `Net::SNMP` itself. 2) Try enabling debug mode: `$session->debug([$mask]);` 3) Check/increase `max_msg_size`: `$octets = $session->max_msg_size([$octets]);`

Answer (score 1):

From the man page:
     Set  the max-repetitions field in the GETBULK PDU.  This specifies the maximum number of iterations over the repeating
               variables.
Example

```
   snmpbulkget -v2c -Cn1 -Cr5 -Os -c public zeus system ifTable

   will retrieve the variable system.sysDescr.0 (which is the lexicographically next object to system) and the first 5 objects in
   the ifTable:

   sysDescr.0 = STRING: "SunOS zeus.net.cmu.edu 4.1.3_U1 1 sun4m"
   ifIndex.1 = INTEGER: 1
   ifIndex.2 = INTEGER: 2
   ifDescr.1 = STRING: "lo0"
   et cetera.
```

Comment: So it looks like it wont retry based on max repetitions.

Comment: I am starting to think that it's for maximum number of repetions of a given query to get the full data from the query. In this case,to get the full interface table data. And it's not an actual retry to query the data over again

Comment: I just had a look at CPAN and there is a retries field in session.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the docs, but do you really think a query will be retried even if it is sent successfully and the host returns results (albeit incomplete)?

Comment: I guess, It's just the number of retries on time out that we specifity through a session retry. But again, expecting otherwise ( retrying even if the query is successful) doesn't sound like a valid use case. If I add a retry to the query , it would be a work around to ensure the data is probably correct